# Parsing postgres query to sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm working on small app and have hanged on creating query in sqlalchemy.

Postgres Query:

```
    with skills as (
        select distinct skill_name
        from backend.skill
        where skill_name in ('Spark', 'Oracle', 'Dataflow')
        order by skill_name
    )

    select 
        coalesce(p.yoe, 0)
    from 
        skills s
    left join backend.skill ss ON s.skill_name = ss.skill_name
    left join backend.person_skill p ON ss.id_skill = p.id_skill
    where exists (
        select 1 from backend.person_skill p1
        join backend.skill ss1 ON p1.id_skill = ss1.id_skill
        where p1.id_person = 1
    )
    order by ss.skill_name
```

Query works perfectly fine from pgadmin panel and gives desired output.

Basicaly I need to fetch data from person_skill based on keywords input. The input is List of strings (skill names). I need to fetch `yoe` field from person_skill. If person doesn't have the given skill, yoe equals 0. I would appreciate a little help :)

Comment: I'm unclear what you're asking. Is the question, "how do I create this query using sqlalchemy"? We would need to see your model definitions to answer that question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've managed to do it on my own.

```
    _skills = (
        database.query(models.Skill.skill_name.label("skill_name"), models.Skill.id_skill.label("id_skill"))
        .where(sa.func.lower(models.Skill.skill_name).in_(skills))
        .distinct()
        .subquery()
    )
    _person = (database.query(models.Person_skill).where(models.Person_skill.id_person == id).exists())
    
    query = (
        database.query(sa.func.coalesce(models.Person_skill.yoe, 0).label("yoe"))
        .select_from(_skills)
        .join(models.Person_skill, models.Person_skill.id_skill == _skills.c.id_skill, isouter=True)
        .where(_person)
        .order_by(_skills.c.skill_name)
        .all()
    )
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).